# Grunt, Sass, and gitignore: Compiled CSS and .map files?

Tags: git, sass, gruntjs, gitignore

I inherited a site that's using Grunt and SASS. The last company that worked on this site seems to have removed `Git`. They also removed any `Grunt`-related files except for the `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` for some reason. I installed `Git` and `Grunt`, but I'm unsure how Grunt and Sass work entirely. I figured out how to recompile the CSS files using Grunt.

As it was without me changing any files, running `grunt` gives the following output.

```
styles.css
File "css/styles.css" prefixed.
responsive.css
File "css/responsive.css" prefixed.
old.css
File "css/old.css" prefixed.
```

And I see that `*.css` are the files that are compiled. . So, I figured if I remove `*.css`, they should be recreated, but *they don't* - only `styles.css` does and the other files don't get recreated. I need to have a copy of `responsive.css` an `old.css` for them to get updated. I also noticed that these two files' contents don't actually get updated (I placed comments which persisted), but files are re-saved causing `Git` to flag them modified.

**Question #1:** Why this behavior? I do see references to only `styles.css` in `Gruntfile.js`. Could that be it? If so, why doesn't it resave `responsive.css` and `old.css`? I'm unsure how to version-control these.

**Question #2:** Then, there are `*.css.map` files that get generated as well. What is this? Somtimes, not always, I would also see errors in the browser console like below (Magento site). I have no idea why it's looking in the `media` directory. They're in `skin/frontend/blueacorn/mysite/css/`. I would assume to gitignore these.

```
X GET http://mysite/media/css/styles.css.map
X GET http://mysite/media/css/responsive.css.map
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'nested',
                    sourcemap: true
                },
                files: {
                    'css/styles.css': 'sass/styles.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'],
                map: true
            },
            multiple_files: {
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                src: 'css/*.css',
                dest: 'css/'
            }
        },

        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'images/',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: 'images/'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            options: {
                plugins: [{
                    removeViewBox: false
                }]
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'images/',
                    src: ['**/*.scg'],
                    dest: 'images'
                }]
            }
        },

        cssmin: {
            combine: {
                files: {
                    'css/styles.css': ['css/styles.css']
                }
            }
        },

        jshint: {
            src: ['js/*.js','js/**/*.js']
        },

        watch: {
            images: {
                files: ['images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}', 'images/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                tasks: ['imagemin'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            js: {
                files: ['js/*.js','js/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            svgs: {
                files: ['images/*.svg','images/**/*.svg'],
                task: ['svgmin'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            css: {
                files: ['sass/*.scss', 'sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass','autoprefixer'],
                sourceComments: 'normal',
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        },

        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 8000,
                    base: './'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['imagemin','svgmin','sass','autoprefixer','jshint']);

    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['connect', 'watch']);

    grunt.registerTask('production', ['imagemin','sass','autoprefixer','cssmin']);

}
```

Comment: The `.css.map` files are generated by SASS to help you debug the CSS using the developer tools in the browser. They aren't really needed for production, so gitignore is fine. Also: You'll get more help if you paste bin the `Gruntfile.js` for us to peruse.

Answer (score 0):

So the only files that sass is actually compiling are `styles.css` -- you can think of grunt as building commands through nested structures, for example the "sass" section of the file is saying to run `sass --nested --sourcemap=true css/styles.scss:css/styles.css`, which will compile `styles.scss` into `styles.css`, ensuring to create a sourcemap. You can add any other files you want to be compiled below the `'css/styles.css' : 'sass/styles.scss'` line.

Autoprefixing, which is what's being run on the other two files, just adds browser-specific prefixes to styles that need it, ie.

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

gets compiled to

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-mozilla-border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
```

`*.css.map` is actually pretty cool -- it maps all of your sass declarations to css declarations.  If you're using git, you probably don't need to include it in the repository.